# ggplot error with date string on x-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, posixct

I am trying to plot `localminute` as x-axis and `meter_value` as y-axis. Dataset has 11.9K rows, here's a snippet:

```
localminute,dataid,meter_value
2016-01-01 05:18:49.497023-06,35,98178  
2016-01-01 05:45:43.51577-06,35,98182  
2016-01-01 05:57:45.024395-06,35,98184  
2016-01-01 06:08:41.532267-06,35,98186  
2016-01-01 06:36:50.053034-06,35,98188  
2016-01-01 06:56:53.066606-06,35,98192  
2016-01-01 08:57:53.65758-06,35,98212
```

I used "ggplot" comment but got error "error in usemethod("depth") :...

```
test <- read.csv("test_35.csv")  #read data in csv file, to plot data
ggplot(test, aes(x=localminute, y=meter_value)) + geom_point() +
      ggtitle("meter value for dataID=35") +
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, hjust=1))

Error in UseMethod("depth") : 
  no applicable method for 'depth' applied to an object of class "NULL"`
```

Comment: You ought to convert the first column to POSIXct

Comment: I was unable to replicate this error.  Perhaps it's related to https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2514.

Comment: Show us `str(yourdata)`, is `localminute` a string, POSIXct or what? If it isn't POSIXct, convert it to one.

Comment: `> str(test)
'data.frame': 11872 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ localminute: Factor w/ 11872 levels "2015-10-01 00:14:44-05",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ dataid     : int  35 35 35 35 35 35 35 35 35 35 ...
 $ meter_value: int  93470 93470 93470 93470 93470 93470 93470 93470 93470 93470 ...`

Comment: I plotted 11872 data in R. but how should I verify that all 11872 data is plotted in R.

Answer (score 1):

Specify the format of the variables when reading the file:

```
test <- read.csv('test_35.csv', colClasses = c('POSIXct','integer','integer'))
```

Comment: hi carlos lagosta, thanks for your suggested code. I can plot the data. I use 'ggplot(test, aes(x = localminute, y = meter_value)) + geom_point() + ggtitle("meter value for dataID=35") + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))' , so the output plot X-axis displayed only Oct, Jan, Apr. May I know how to adjust the X-axis (localminute) to "dd/mm/yyyy h:mm". The gap should be one month each.

Comment: Check the documentation for scale_x_datetime